# Error encoding arguments at position 2

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

I keep getting following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token “ in JSON at position 2

when I try to call following function, below is how I call it.

["ADDRESS","ADDRESS"],"STRING"

This is the function I'm trying to call.

```
    function demoteManyPeople(address[] people, string whyThough) external {
        require(people.length < 10);
        for (uint index = 10; index > people.length; index--) {
             qualifiedForDemote[people[index]] = false;
             DemotePeople(people[index], whyThough);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just ran into this error in Remix, and my issue was I didn't wrap the argument with quotes.